# "My hobby is to play basketball" or "My hobby is playing basketball"?

Tags: grammar

Which one is more correct:

> My hobby is to play basketball.

or

> My hobby is playing basketball?

Answer (score 2):

I’d say **my hobby is playing basketball** because it’s taking place now in the present, has been for some time in the past and may be in future.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Lucian Sava that

> My hobby is playing basketball?

is the better choice, as a statement, or a question if someone asked you. As for

> My hobby is to play basketball.

This wording seems to indicate a future goal, but seems strange written here. You could similarly say:

> "The hobby *I am interested in* is to play basketball."

which shows that "is to play" is referring to a future event. Also you could say:

> My *goal* is to play basketball.

which also refers to a future event.